# Assign different muliple foreign key in one table from other table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

[image]I was planning to make 2 tables for user infomation . The first lager table named **userInfo** has all data . The second smaller table named **loginDetails** have the minimum data to log in .

My problem is : I could not assign multiple foreign key .

**MySQL said:
#1005 - Can't create table `test`.`logindetails` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

Here is code :

```
CREATE TABLE userInfo
(
userInfoUserNumber INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
userInfoUserName VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
userInfoPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
userInfoFirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
userInfoLastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
userInfoPhoneNumber INT(255) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
userInfoPlaceWithoutDivision VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
userInfoDivision VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
userInfoEmail VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
userInfoProfilePicture VARCHAR(255),

PRIMARY KEY (userInfoUserNumber)
);


CREATE TABLE loginDetails
(
loginDetailsUserNumber INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
loginDetailsUserName VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
loginDetailsPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
loginDetailsPhoneNumber INT(255) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
loginDetailsEmail VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,

PRIMARY KEY (loginDetailsUserNumber) ,
FOREIGN KEY (loginDetailsUserName) REFERENCES userInfo(userInfoUserName)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (loginDetailsPassword) REFERENCES userInfo(userInfoPassword)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (loginDetailsPhoneNumber) REFERENCES userInfo(userInfoPhoneNumber)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (loginDetailsEmail) REFERENCES userInfo(userInfoEmail) 
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

[ In short : suppose my first table has 10 columns , my second table has 5 columns , i want to choose any 4 columns from 1st table and copy to my second table ]

Question 2 :

why this statement is error ? please explain

```
INSERT INTO userInfo(userInfoUserName,userInfoPassword,userInfoFirstName,userInfoLastName,userInfoPhoneNumber,userInfoPlaceWithoutDivision,userInfoDivision)
VALUES (cat,SHA1(cat),white,cat,01111111111,myplace,mydivision);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a foreign key only if the column you reference is the leftmost column of a key.

Traditionally, you'd reference only a unique or primary key, but InnoDB (strangely) allows a foreign key to reference any kind of key or partial key.

Your column `userInfo.userInfoPassword` is not part of any key.

It's not clear what purpose there could be for declaring all those foreign keys. If you want them to cascade, to always remain the same value in the userInfo table, then why are they stored in both tables at all? Just store them in one table.

---

> i want to create a different table (loginDetails) taking 4 columns from userinfo

Why? You don't have to create a different table if you want to fetch a result set with just those four columns. You just specify the columns you want in a query instead of using `SELECT *`.

```
SELECT loginDetailsUserNumber,
  loginDetailsUserName,
  loginDetailsPassword,
  loginDetailsPhoneNumber,
  loginDetailsEmail
FROM userInfo;
```

Another option would be to use `CREATE VIEW` to define a view with  those four columns, and then you could use `SELECT *` from your view.

```
CREATE VIEW loginDetails AS
  SELECT loginDetailsUserNumber,
    loginDetailsUserName,
    loginDetailsPassword,
    loginDetailsPhoneNumber,
    loginDetailsEmail
  FROM userInfo;

SELECT * FROM loginDetails;
```

Comment: userinfo table has many other columns , i want to create a different table (loginDetails) taking 4 columns from userinfo

Answer (score 1):

When designing foreign key relationships, you should be linking using *primary keys*.  This would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE loginDetails (
    loginDetailsUserNumber INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    loginDetailsUserInfoUserNumber INT UNSIGNED,
    loginDetailsUserName VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    loginDetailsPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    loginDetailsPhoneNumber INT(255) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    loginDetailsEmail VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (loginDetailsUserNumber) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (loginDetailsUserInfoUserNumber) REFERENCES userInfo(userInfoUserNumber)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

In other words, you can keep the duplicated columns (perhaps a user changes his/her name or password and you want the version associated with the login).  BUT, you should be assigning a user number at login and putting that id in the table.